# Jackson: how to deserialize nested custom maps and lists?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize an untyped JSON file into a custom implementation of Map interface.
This custom map implementation can have only java simple types (`Date`, `String`, `Integer`, `Long`) and nested types (Custom Map implementation for nested map and custom List implementation for nested arrays or lists)

I tried the following:

```
CustomMap map = mapper.readValue(myJsonFile, CustomMap.class);
```

I got the expected type except for nested maps I get `HashMap` type and for nested arrays I get `ArrayList` type.

I think Jackson fallbacks on `HashMap` for unknown types and `ArrayList` for arrays.

Is it possible to fallback recursively to `CustomMap` instead of `HashMap` for unknown subtypes and `CustomList` for arrays?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating and registering a `SimpleModule` on your mapper. This will allow to change the type mapping for `Map` in your case and other types like `List`. E.g.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("CustomCollections", Version.unknownVersion());
module.addAbstractTypeMapping(Map.class, CustomMap.class);
module.addAbstractTypeMapping(List.class, CustomList.class);
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

You may have to call `readValue` like this:

```
Map<String, Object> data = mapper.readValue(myJsonFile, new TypeReference<CustomMap<String, Object>>() {});
```

Mind that this works in Jackson 2.6.0 and later as there was a [bug](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/700) previously.

Also, Jackson defaults to `LinkedHashMap` for `Map` not `HashMap`, to maintain the order of data in the JSON document.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I got a JsonMappingException:
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Method     provided only as it is needed for Map interface.
 We do not wish to expose general purpose add method.

Note: I have the 2.6.2 jackson version

Comment: Finally, this exception is thrown because public boolean add(Object value) method is not correctly implemented in CustomList. I will find a workaround for this and update this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Solution proposed by Manos works, in my case I need to add a custom deserializer for CustomList, due to a missing implementation of a method.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("CustomCollections", Version.unknownVersion());
module.addAbstractTypeMapping(Map.class, CustomMap.class);
module.addAbstractTypeMapping(List.class, CustomList.class);
module.addDeserializer(CustomList.class, new CustomListDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```